# Trophies in pre-owned Vita game

Tags: ps-vita

When I go to start a pre-owned game, I am met by this ominous warning:

> #### You cannot earn trophies in this application. Do you still want to start this application?
>
> Only the first player to use an application can earn trophies. To earn trophies, you must delete all data related to this application and then start the application.

I don't have any data on my system and can't find data to delete. Does this mean I need to delete it from the original owner's Vita? Am I SOL or is there some easy way around this?

[image: Touch My Katamari]

Comment: Do you have a white Vita? I didn't know it came in other colours.

Comment: @Colin: I know the one that comes with the [Assassin's Creed 3: Liberation Bundle](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51DmnCeFfCL._AA300_.jpg) is white. I'm not sure if there are other ways of obtaining one.

Comment: I think there may be some stored data on the game card itself?

Comment: I hate yes/no dialogs. For one thing the subtitle could mislead you into thinking "yes" means "delete all data and start app", secondly the options should really be "Start without trophies" and "erase save data and start"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to reset the save stored on the Vita game's cart. To do so, simply delete the game's "bubble" from the menu, it will tell you this will delete the save stored on the card and enable trophy earning.

[Source](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/feature.asp?t=how_to&c=38334)

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. It doesn't have to do with the game itself being previously used on another Vita.